# Custom Exception with a constructor that takes parameters

Tags: apex, exception

I'd like to extend [Exception](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception.htm) to create a custom exception class that takes several arguments in addition to the standard string message.

I've found examples showing basic inheritance ([An Introduction to Exception Handling](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling#How_do_I_use_custom_exceptions.3F)) and adding custom constructors ([Extended Class Example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_example.htm)).

```
public virtual class MyException extends Exception {
    public Double d;

    // Exception class constructor     
    MyException(string message, Double d) {
        // How can I pass 'message' to the base constructor?
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

When using a custom exception similar to the example above calls to getMessage() return 'Script-thrown exception', which makes sense as message hasn't been utilized yet.

**How can I extend Exception and include a custom constructor such that Exception.getMessage() returns a string specified in the constructor?**

Or more generally, how do I pass arguments from my custom constructor to the base constructor in Apex?

Comment: I'm not too familiar yet with Apex, but in other languages you can invoke the base constructor. Is that not possible in Apex? Your links don't say either way.

Comment: @MikeChale When I'm not writing Apex I'm writing .NET. So I was looking for the equivalent of the [base keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce(v=vs.110).aspx) for specifying which base-class constructor should be called when creating instances of the derived class. I haven't found how to do this yet.

Comment: Looks like I want [super](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_super.htm)

Comment: I'm a .Net guy, too. Oh well.

Comment: @MikeChale Sometimes I feel a bit out of place because I like .NET and Visual Studio as well as Salesforce. :) Oh well. Do you think there would be any value in a question about how a primarily .NET developer can work with apex? Might be a bit too general.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be too general. I'm just going through the SF Apex guides as a start.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use this(message) in your constructor to call the base class constructor:

```
public virtual class MyException extends Exception
{
    public Decimal d;

    public MyException(String message, Decimal d)
    {
        this(message);
        this.d = d;
    }

    @isTest
    static void test()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new MyException('this is my message',3.1415);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            system.assertEquals('this is my message', e.getMessage());
            MyException me = (MyException) e;
            system.assertEquals('this is my message', me.getMessage());
            system.assertEquals(3.1415, me.d);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I would have expected the System Exception class to behave like a virtual Apex class (and therefore be able to use super(message) in this situation).

Comment: When I tried `super(message)` I wasn't able to save/compile the class. The error message was "Save error: Object has no superclass for super invocation".

Comment: Yes, same here. I think that perhaps Exception is a special case. For a long time Exception was the **only** class that could be extended in Apex, so there may be a historical reason.

Comment: it really make no sense that you'd need to call `this` instead of `super`... Just another inconsistency in the apex language

Comment: Apex Exceptions are special, and behind the scenes, Apex defines the "default" Constructors for you.  If you try to define an Exception: `public with sharing class SampleException extends Exception { public SampleException() { super(); } }` you get a compile error: `System exception constructor already defined: void <init>() (Line: ___, Column: __)
classes/InboundEmail.cls: Method is not visible: void System.ApexBaseException.<init>() (Line: ___, Column: _)`.

Comment: I wish we could add our own "default" constructors.  For instance, when a SObjectField is null, throw an Exception which uses a Custom Label for the Message so the messange and Field Label are translated automatically.  `public virtual class NullSObjectFieldException extends Exception { public NullSObjectFieldException(SObjectField field) { this.setMessage(String.format(System.Label.Field_Cannot_Be_Null, new String[] { field == null ? 'null' : Schema.EmailMessage.RelatedToId.getDescribe().getLabel() }
  )); } }`

Answer (score 7):

I found one possible solution in the post [Custom Exception message](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Custom-Exception-message/td-p/192956) by Corey_B.

In the custom constructor explicitly call [setMessage](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm#exception_common_methods). E.g.

```
public virtual class MyException extends Exception {
    public Double d;

    // Exception class constructor     
    MyException(string message, Double d) {
        // Pass 'message' to the base class
        this.setMessage(message);

        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

This does solve my explicit issue, but doesn't really address how to handle base constructors with inheritance.

---

**Update** for "how do I pass arguments from my custom constructor to the base constructor in Apex?"

I tried using `super(message);` as the first line of the constructor but it resulted in the error:

> Save error: Object has no superclass for super invocation

So I'm assuming that Exception isn't virtual.

> "Only classes that are extending from virtual or abstract classes can use super." [[Super keyword](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_super.htm)]

Comment: Did you try using this.super keyword?

Comment: @doga Yes I did, as per my answer I received a save error. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

This.setMessage() seems like the only plausible alternative.
If you're just bothered about the message you could try this.
http://th3silverlining.com/2009/06/11/throwing-custom-apex-exceptions/

Comment: That is how I've previously been handling custom exceptions. It does bother me that I can extend Exception and still use the Exception constructors but not invoke them via Super.

Answer (score -2):

I think following can help you. It has complete example of SFDC APEX standard and custom exceptions

http://share-salesforce.blogspot.in/2013/05/salesforce-apex-exception-handling-and_29.html